# Examples of open-source code which contain extensive examples of Immutable classes?

Tags: java, open-source, immutability

I am looking for realistic examples of immutable classes developed in Java. In order to allow finding those classes which are intended to be immutable, it would be helpful if the code used an `@Immutable` annotation, or otherwise documented classes as intended to be immutable. I also need to be able to study the source code of those classes, so a project with any "read only" license is suitable.

In regards to the `@Immutable` annotation used, it doesn't matter *which* `@Immutable` it is. So whether the annotation is from JSR-305 or FindBugs, or in-house, etc., it doesn't matter, just that the simple name of the annotation is "Immutable". Similarly, if the project uses a *consistent* way of marking classes as immutable (class name convention, javadoc, marker interfaces, etc.) such that I can search the codebase and tell a mutable class from an immutable one, this is also what I'm looking for.

Are there any examples of open-source code containing extensive examples of immutable classes?

Comment: Sorry don't know of any, but it seems like a useful exercise if you find example where it's not done, to go through and submit that as a patch

Comment: Will this link help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307232/immutable-beans-in-java/307284#307284

Any reason why @Immutable but not `interface Immutable`?

Comment: @yclian: only that I never thought of using a marker interface at the time of writing :) All I'm really after from each codebase is a consistent way of finding the classes which were intended to be immutable. If that means that it's a convention in the class name, field names, package location, javadoc, or whatever, it doesn't matter, just as long as I can find when a class was meant to be immutable or not.

Comment: @yclian: edited to be a bit clearer about this :)

Answer (score 3):

Most classes in these libraries are immutable:

- [Joda Date/Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/faq.html)
- [Joda Money](http://joda-money.sourceforge.net/)

No `Immutable` annotation in the code, tough, AFAIK.

**EDIT** The project uses documentation mostly. One key aspect though: if you don't want your classes to be mutable, provide no (public) setters. If client code cannot modify the state of your objects, then you have got effectively an immutable class. This is a principle, both Joda time as well as joda money use. Off the top of my head, I could not name a single mutable class in either libraries (I have so far used only the immutable ones, and never missed mutable versions at all.)

Comment: I will look into these two, thanks. Although there's no Immutable annotation, do you know of any other convention the project uses to tell immutable from mutable?

Comment: (re: edit) for clarity's sake, I'm not looking for *how* to write immutable classes, just trying to find example classes that real developers come up with in order to make a certain code analysis tool a bit more robust :-)

Comment: Looking at the Joda Time code, there seems to be consistent mentions of "xxx is thread safe and immutable" in javadoc. Looks very useful for my purposes, +1.